# Why ASP.NET MVC doesn´t send a response when I call Json(null)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, model-view-controller, json.net

There is any good reason to not send a response when I call Json(null) in ASP.NET MVC Action?

Because it triggers the fail event on jQuery Ajax call instead of done.

The code that do that is:

```
public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
{
    ...
        if (Data != null)
        {
            JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            if (MaxJsonLength.HasValue)
            {
                serializer.MaxJsonLength = MaxJsonLength.Value;
            }
            if (RecursionLimit.HasValue)
            {
                serializer.RecursionLimit = RecursionLimit.Value;
            }
            response.Write(serializer.Serialize(Data));
        }
}
```

It seems a fool question, but I am asking it because I am overrding the Json method, removing that if. So my $.ajax call will work, calling done event instead of fail.
But if ASP.NET MVC Team put that "if" maybe they had a good reason, that could impact my application

```
        //jQuery 1.9.1
        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            url: urlGeraSigla,
            data: { titulo: $(this).val() },
            dataType: "json",
            type: 'POST'
        }).done(function (resultadoJson) {
            $('#@(Html.IdFor(model => model.Sigla))').val(resultadoJson);
        }).fail(function(resultadoJson) {
            debugger;//ASP.NET MVC Json(null) hit here
        });
```

Comment: what version of jquery?

Comment: Strange that it would not respond with an empty response. Honestly I replaced the Javascript serializer with JSON.Net. I discovered a few issues like the one you encountered.

Comment: @Chuck Conway, actually I am replacing it too, creating a JsonNetResult class (it should have a flag to do it autommatically and set that flag to true on new templates). But I keep that "IF" in mine JsonNetResult to not break any existing code